# Import-Pssession is not importing cmdlets when used in a custom module

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a PowerShell script/function that works great when I use it in my PowerShell profile or manually copy/paste the function in the PowerShell window.

I'm trying to make the function accessible to other members of my team as a module.  I want to have the module stored in a central place so we can all add it to our PSModulePath.

Here is a copy of the basic function:

```
Function Connect-O365{
    $o365cred = Get-Credential username@domain.onmicrosoft.com
    $session365 = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ -Credential $o365cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
    Import-PSSession $session365 -AllowClobber
}
```

If I save this function in my PowerShell profile it works fine.  I can dot source a *.ps1 script with this function in it and it works as well.

The issue is when I save the function as a *.psm1 PowerShell script module.  The function runs fine but none of the exported commands from the Import-PSSession are available.  I think this may have something to do with the module scope.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to get around this.

#### EDIT

When I create the following module and run Connect-O365 the imported cmdlets will not be available.

```
$scriptblock = {
    Function Connect-O365 {
        $o365cred = Get-Credential username@domain.onmicrosoft.com
        $session365 = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/" -Credential $o365cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
        Import-PSSession $session365 -AllowClobber
    }
}

New-Module -Name "Office 365" -ScriptBlock $scriptblock
```

When I import the next module without the Connect-O365 function the imported cmdlets are available.

```
$scriptblock = {
    $o365cred = Get-Credential username@domain.onmicrosoft.com
    $session365 = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/" -Credential $o365cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
    Import-PSSession $session365 -AllowClobber
}

New-Module -Name "Office 365" -ScriptBlock $scriptblock
```

This appears to be a scope issue of some sort, just not sure how to get around it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With some assistance from TechNet I was able to modify the script module so it worked the way I expected.

```
function Connect-O365 {
    $o365cred = Get-Credential username@domain.onmicrosoft.com
    $session365 = New-PSSession `
                    -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange `
                    -ConnectionUri "https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/" `
                    -Credential $o365cred `
                    -Authentication Basic `
                    -AllowRedirection 
    Import-Module (Import-PSSession $session365 -AllowClobber) -Global
}
```

[TechNet Post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/529bd0ef-5e88-4808-a5ac-dc07ca8660f3/#517c8111-54c6-4f32-b9ae-bb73c9ebc138)

Comment: Thankfully I was able to +1 both Q&A. Thank you for this. I would suggest you mark as the answer.