# When using a function within a Powershell module, a psm1, is it possible to export the ExchangeOnline functions to be accessible in the console?

Tags: powershell, office365

Working on several Powershell functions which connect to Office365 services and automate many of my usual tasks. Found when I have the function in a psm1, running the function to connect to ExchangeOnline the functions are not exposed to the console and only functions within the same module.

While I know I can export-modulemember, this only works for functions when the module is loaded, happens well before I connect-office365 -exchangeonline.

Is there anyway to export the commands loaded when connecting to Office 365 after connecting?

By placing the following function in a psm1 instead of a ps1 and loading it, and then running connect-off365 -exchangeonline, all Exchange Online related commands are not usable in the console. Yet, having the same function in a ps1 and loading it, the ExchangeOnline functions work.

```
Function Connect-Office365 {
    Param(
        [Switch]$ExchangeOnline,
        [Switch]$EO
    )

    if ($EO) { $ExchangeOnline = $true }
    elseif ($EO -and $ExchangeOnline) { Write-Warning "No need to declare ExchangeOnline and EO" }

    $Credential = Get-Credential -message "Enter Office 365 credentials,`r`nor cancel to not connect to Office 365"
    if ($null -eq $Credential) { Write-Host "Skipped entering credentials"; $TryAgain = $False }
    if ($ExchangeOnline) {
        Write-Host "Connecting to Exchange Online Services"
        $global:ExchangeSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $Credential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection -EA stop
        Import-PSSession $global:ExchangeSession -AllowClobber -DisableNameChecking
    }
}
```

For example

```
PS C:\Users\TechWithAHammer> import-module C:\scripts\Connect-Office365.psm1    
PS C:\Users\TechWithAHammer> connect-office365 -eo                                                                        Connecting to MSOL Services                                                                                             Connecting to Exchange Online Services

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     1.0        tmp_3zvdxnnc.gd0                    {Add-AvailabilityAddressSpace, Add-DistributionGroupMember...


PS C:\Users\TechWithAHammer> get-mailbox
get-mailbox : The term 'get-mailbox' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-mailbox
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (get-mailbox:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the answer in [Commands from implicit remoting module not available when created from another module's function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24249271/commands-from-implicit-remoting-module-not-available-when-created-from-another-m?rq=1), found that I had to use Import-Module to import the Exchange Online and Compliance and Security center modules into the global session.

Import-Module (Import-PSSession $global:ExchangeSession -AllowClobber -DisableNameChecking) -Global